# How can I play Starcraft II on my TV

Tags: starcraft-2, pc, monitor

I can play other games with my TV as my monitor.  (IE I play Skyrim all the time with my TV as my monitor.)

But when I fire up Starcraft II I get a very scrambled picture.

My TV runs best at 1280 X 768, but it does support some other resolutions.  Would a different resolution help?  Is there any hope to get this working?

Any why doesn't Starcraft II work but Skyrim does?

Answer (score 1):

Try windowed mode, that should fix it since it's not changing the screen mode.

Then look around for a borderless window mode for SC2. You may have to use 3rd party software.

Answer (score 1):

As Zeno said, try Windowed mode.  I currently run Starcraft II on a 2-monitor setup, and I run it in windowed mode.  **As an added bonus**:  You'll want to check the box for full screen windowed mode (this removes the border around the window and makes it feel the same as if it were in a  "normal" non-windowed mode).